# mySQL query on matching all values in stored comma separated values in column

Tags: sql, csv, match

I have been searching for quite some time and foound multiple solutions for doing what I need backwards but not going the direction I need.

I have a column of values, these are requirements that must be met to use the record.

```
|id  | name  | required |
|1   | yes   | 2,3,23   |
|2   | no    | 2,3,7    |
```

Before the query runs I have an array of all the exsisting required values, this of course can be placed into a comma del string as well.

Example is I have an array (1,2,3,18,23), and I need to pull the correct record id #1 because my array meets all requirements.

I am always amazed at some queries to do things, but I am not finding a solution to this one.

thanks
-Chris

Comment: This isn't very clear to me. Can you explain why row `1` meets the requirements, but row `2` doesn't? All required values for row `2` appear in the array too.

Comment: I am sorry, that is correct let me update row 2 to add a number NOT in the array.

Comment: I don't think this is really possible with a simple query so I handled it in Php by pulling the list, exploding it, getting an array count.  Then using array_intersect to see if counts match, then collecting the record ID's then doing a query with IN ().